# Simplexml xpath to attribute value and and child node values in one query

Tags: xpath, attributes, simplexml, nodes

example XML:

```
<users> 
  <user id="fakeuserid">

    <password>fakeuserpassword</password>

    <username>fakeusername</username>

  </user>

  <user id="anotherfakeuserid">

    <password>anotherfakeuserpassword</password>

    <username>anotherfakeusername</username>

  </user>
</users>
```

I would like to be able to access the id attribute and username value of each user.
How could I do that?
At the moment I am trying it with: /*/user and //user to no avail

Thanks in advance,
Toy

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/users/user/@id | /users/user/username
```

**Do note** the use of the XPath *union* operator `|`

Comment: Dimitri, your idea works, but it returns two sets of values. 
I am trying to return one recordset with an idfield for use in search results and edit forms. 
in this case sql might look like: 
"select * from tblusers" 
xml equivalent: //user 

From there I could access all child nodes: 
user->password,user->username 
but how would I access the value of the id attribute? 

Again thanks in advance for the help

Comment: @Toy: If you have access to an `user` element you cantry issuing another XPath expression against this `user` element: `@id`

Answer (score 0):

In xpath:

- userId = '//user/@id'
- username = '//user/username'

Is this what you're looking for?